# How to implement expand and collapse node in D3 tree structure

Tags: html, json, d3.js

i am running the code in firefox  and i am getting the desired layout but i am stuck while implementing node-expand and node-collapse.

can anyone please help me to solve my problem to implement node-expand and node-collapse.

code used is --

```js
// json file

{
 "name": "Max",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
   }
   ]
 }
 ]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>

 <title>d3 tree</title>
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
 
 
 var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", 5000)
 .attr("height", 500)
 .append("g")
   .attr("transform", "translate(50, 50)");


 var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([400, 400]);


  d3.json("data.json", function (data) { 

   var nodes = tree.nodes(data);
   var links = tree.links(nodes);

   var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
     .attr("class", "node")
     .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; } )

   node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("fill", "steelblue");

   node.append("text")
    .text(function (d) { return d.name; })

   var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection( function(d) { return[d.y, d.x]; });

   canvas.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "#ADADAD")
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  })

  

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the code from [collapsible tree example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083)?